# Unable to add borders to cells in column with background colour which isn't white

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm wanting to add borders to cells in a column in which the background colour is blue.  Previously I was able to do this as usual by doing Right-Click > Format Cells and as far as I recall, selecting Border > Outline and then filling in the borders I wanted but it doesn't seem to be working this time.  I have tried changing the borders for the entire column.  On the cells with white background colour, it is working ok, so the borders are being put in.  It's just that they don't show up on the coloured cells, but the line colour is not the problem as the line colour is black and it works on the other columns which are coloured.
Can anyone help please?  I can't add a screen shot as the information in the file is sensitive.

Comment: can you re-create the problem in another tab ? another workbook ? another section of the sheet ?

Comment: also, just delete the info that is sensitive, take snap shot to upload, close workbook with out saving

Comment: Yes I thought of doing this and may do so if I can find the time.  Thanks.  I've had very little time spare lately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by simply typing text into the cells to the the right of the column with no right-hand border.  I'm not sure if my OP was completely accurate now, as I don't recall whether or not it was only the right-hand border which wasn't visible, or if the other borders were also invisible, as I think I asserted in the OP.  In any case, the problem had now been solved thanks to Dave.  This said, I'd be interested to know if it's possible to have borders show without having to type any text in the cells to the right of the said column.

Answer (score 1):

You might have trailing spaces in your cell, which would prevent the right border from showing.

Or, I think it might be showing, just not very clearly, if the blue is dark enough...

[image]

In this picture, the blue also has a black border...

Perhaps, try making the border color bright red, and seeing if it works then.

Comment: Thanks.  Although it's still not giving the desired result when I change it to bright red, when I go back to the cell I try to give red borders and click on 'Format Cells' again I notice that the color is now set to 'Automatic' and I wonder if this could be the cause of the problem.  Maybe this setting 'Automatic' automatically makes the colour of the borders the same as the background colour, because it does indeed seem that the borders are present but invisible, since the borders show on the cells with white background in the same column below the ones with coloured backgrounds, as I said.

Comment: I said red because that would stand out and you could maybe see if it's a contrast issue...

Comment: Yes I understand that, but there was still no visible border when I selected red.  In fact, I have a number of columns for which the borders do show even though they have coloured backgrounds and the borders are just the standard black colour I was always using.  I'm not sure if I mentioned this in my OP, but if not or you didn't notice it in my OP, your suggestion was sensible, yet to no avail.  It does seem to me that the colour is being automatically set to a colour which isn't visible, possibly exactly the same colour as the background and so my selection is effectively overridden.

Comment: My other ideas, are either there is a bit of text overlapping the border... Or, the dimension of the cell might be a tad off. try resizing the column/row a tiny bit and see if that makes a difference

Comment: Ok will try that thanks.

Comment: I've actually got a border to show in red at the top, bottom and left of a cell, but not at the right and I can't get it to show by selecting the left of the cell to the right either, but at least that's some progress.  I'm not sure if this happened as a result of widening the cell as you suggested or just because I actually clicked on the 'Border' icon in Format Cells, which i'd thought would be done automatically before.  I think it's the latter as I just changed the column back to its original width and the red borders still show, except for the right hand one and I do want this one to show

Comment: then it's most probably text that is escaping to the right... try wrapping the cell, or editing the cell and clicking after the last character in the cell, and pressing the DELETE key for a bit to get rid of any tiny characters that may have slipped in there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118619/discussion-between-george-tomlinson-and-dave).